# Using a map element in MATCH statement

Tags: dictionary, neo4j, cypher

I have a query written out where one of the lines is as follows:

```
[individualNode IN listOfNodes | [(individualNode)-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(otherNode) | {node:otherNode, similarity:individualNode['similarity']}]] AS connectionMap
```

listOfNodes is a List of maps
Example of one of the map in the list is

```
{
  "similarity":0.25,
  "node":{
    "identity":12345,
    "labels": [
      "Label1",
      "Label2"
    ],
  "properties": {
    yada..yada..
  }
}
```

The issue here is that since individualNode is a map the statement (individualNode)-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(otherNode) will fail.

So my question is how do i access the node to use in the match statement, but still retain the map so i can grab the similarity value.

Disclaimer: I know node is a special word in cypher, i only used it here so you guys know what it is i am talking about in the map. That's not how it is in my actual query.
I also change the names of things because i cannot reveal the actual information in the map.

I have tried to write it as (individualNode.node)-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(otherNode) or (individualNode['node'])-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(otherNode) but both throw errors too.

Comment: how did you come up with listOfNodes? pls show us your code not just a part of it. Thanks.

Comment: It was created via pattern comprehension. If you can just imagine [map,map,map,..] with each map being like above. I don;t think how it was generated is really relevant because individualNode IN listOfNodes will pull each map out.

Comment: Thanks. My question is important because if that is a path (i dont trust the meaning of variable names) then nodes of the path is nodes(path).

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is it syntax error or missing a clause? Please post the error messages as well

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use it later?

You can access maps with their keys, e.g. `map.node`
if you want to use that in a pattern you have to alias it with an identifier

e.g. `WITH map.node as startNode MATCH (startNode)-->(...)`

if you have a list of nodes like in your case you either can walk through that in a pattern comprehension again, like you already did

or you can use `UNWIND` to turn the list into rows.

```
UNWIND listOfNodesMaps as map
WITH map.node as startNode, map.similarity as similarity
MATCH (startNode)-->(...)
```